# Please explain/provide example of difference between gd and 1gd commands?

Tags: search, normal-mode, jump

I was reading the vim :help docs and stumbled upon the `gd` and `1gd` normal mode commands.

But I haven't been able to grasp what's the difference. The docs says:

> ```
>                        *1gd*
> ```
>
> 1gd           Like "gd", but ignore matches inside a {} block that
> ends before the cursor position.

I tried to match the `bar` function declarations in this JS file:

```
foo();
bar();

function foo() {
  bar();
  function bar() {
  }
}

function bar() {
}
```

But regardless at which line was the cursor and which command I used — I always jumped to the correct local declaration of the function, i.e. when I was on line with the `bar();` call inside the foo() function declaration I never reached the bar declaration outside the foo declaration.

So could someone explain this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was designed to work with C as help states, plus description explains how it works:

```
            First Vim searches for the start of the current
            function, just like "[[".  If it is not found the
            search stops in line 1.  If it is found, Vim goes back
            until a blank line is found.  From this position Vim
            searches for the keyword under the cursor, like with
            "*", but lines that look like a comment are ignored
```

and `[[` goes to a section backwards or to the previous `{` in the first column.

In your example there is no section (formfeed) and there is no `{` in the first column so it always go to the line 1 and searches for the keyword from there.

If you move `{` from line 4 to line 5 column 1, there would be a difference between `1gd` and `gd`.

[image: asciicast]

Comment: thank you, that's pretty enogh, the only thing is that in my vim instance it didn't work the same way as on your video: no difference, even when I put the { to line 5 and all other opening { too. Worked the same, probably some option affected it